# Trouble on multiple autocomplete fields on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, dialog

I am using jQuery v1.8.3 and jQuery UI v1.9.2. I implemented [Autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete) and [Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) widgets this way:

```
$("#A_autocomplete").autocomplete({
  select   : function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();

    if ( condition ) {
      // Open a modal dialog window
      $("#dialog_window").dialog('open');
    } else {
      // Populate the autocomplete input with the label (not the value)
      $(this).val(ui.item.label);
    }
  },
  ...
});
```

In the above code, when `condition` is `false` then the autocomplete `#A_autocomplete` works as expected. When `condition` is `true` then the dialog is opened and an AJAX request is executed in order to populate *its* body content with the response HTML data. That HTML data includes another autocomplete field with an `id` of `#B_autocomplete`, and even this autocomplete field works as expected.

However, after the dialog window is closed, the autocomplete `#A_autocomplete` does *not* work anymore as it should: the `$(this).val(ui.item.label)` seems do *not* be triggered anymore.

How can I solve the problem?

---

I noted that, after opening the dialog, in the DOM body are present *two* autocomplete menus:

```html
# Generated "by" / "for" the #A_autocomplete
<ul class="ui-autocomplete" id="ui-id-1">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>

# Generated "by" / "for" the #B_autocomplete after the dialog is opened
<ul class="ui-autocomplete" id="ui-id-11">
  <li>...</li>
</ul>
```

I am thinking that the problem may depends from that...

Comment: Interesting, I have never seen a "preventDefault" within an autocomplete event fire management.

Comment: Is `condition` somehow true after the dialog closes? Any way you can reproduce in a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?